# Method can't be resolved to a variable in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have this code in my class:

```
    package recursion;

    public class maxArray {



        private int findMax(int arr[], int N) {
            int maxSoFar = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k <= N; k++)
                if (arr[k] > arr[maxSoFar]) 
                    maxSoFar = k;
            return maxSoFar;
        } // findMax()
    }
```

and I have this on my main method:

```
    package recursion;

    public class maxArrayTest {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            maxArray m = new maxArray(); 
            int[] arr = {1,2,3};
            m.maxArray(arr,7);

        }

    }
```

I'm trying to sort the array but I keep getting this problem:
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method maxArray(int[], int) is undefined for the type maxArray

at recursion.maxArrayTest.main(maxArrayTest.java:9)

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Your method is called `findMax`, not `maxArray`

Comment: your method is called `findMax` and not `maxArray`.

Comment: You method findMax should also be public to be accessed from outside your class

Comment: It would be a good idea to check your code twice before asking a question.

Answer (score 1):

the method is `findMax()` not `maxArray()` and you can't access it in `maxArrayTest` since it's private.

as a side note use PascalCase for class names and camelCase for methods.

Answer (score 0):

it should be

```
m.findMax(arr,7);
```

Change m.maxArray(arr,7); to m.findMax(arr,7);